# Trying to figure out why my URLsession isn't working

Tags: swift, urlsession

I'm currently learning Swift and recreating an app as a project. I have this API that I'm trying to hit but it's just not working, *sometimes*. I put in breakpoints at the completion and sometimes I'll get a hit with response, but a majority of times I won't. Error returns nil btw.

APIService.swift

```swift
import Foundation

final class APIService {
    init(){}
    
    struct Constants{
        static let apiURL = URL(string: "https://public.opendatasoft.com/api/explore/v2.1/catalog/datasets/airbnb-listings/records?limit=100&refine=city%3A%22New%20York%22&refine=room_type%3A%22Entire%20home%2Fapt%22")
        
    }
    
    public func getListings(completion: @escaping (Result<[WindbnbListing], Error>) -> Void) {
        guard let url = Constants.apiURL else {
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                if let error {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
                return
            }
            
            do{
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(WindbnbListingsResponse.self, from: data)
                completion(.success(response.results))
            }catch{
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
                print(String(describing: json))
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

WindbnbListingsResponse.swift

```swift
import Foundation

struct WindbnbListingsResponse: Codable {
    let total_count: Int
    let results: [WindbnbListing]
    
}
```

WindbnbListing.swift

```swift
import Foundation

struct WindbnbListing: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: String?
    let listing_url: String?
    let name: String?
    let summary: String?
    let space: String?
    let description: String?
    let house_rules: String?
    let thumbnail_url: String?
    let medium_url: String?
    let xl_picture_url: String?
    let neighborhood: String?
    let amenities: [String]?
    let price: Int?
    
    //Host info
    let host_name: String
    let host_since: String
    let host_thumbnail_url: String
    let host_picture_url: String
}
```

Heres a glimpse of console output when it somehow works...Breakpoints on `completion(.success(response.results))` and `completion(.failure(error))`

Console output:
`data   Foundation.Data?    598105 bytes    some _1  URLResponse?    0x0000600000266900 error   Error?  nil none completion  () -> ()    0x00000001023b047c Windbnb`partial apply forwarder for closure #1 (Swift.Result<Swift.Array<Windbnb.WindbnbListing>, Swift.Error>) -> () in Windbnb.WindbnbListingsViewViewModel.fetchListings() -> () at 
data    Foundation.Data 598105 bytes
response    Windbnb.WindbnbListingsResponse
`
As you can see, I get a response working sometimes...could it be an endpoint issue where Im being rate limited? Doubtful because in postman I can keep making requests over and over and over with no hiccups

Comment: Could you please post what your `WindbnbListingsResponse` model looks like ?

Comment: Updated! @ShawnFrank

Comment: There's nothing like 'just not working'. Please attach what the console prints after executing the code or where did you put the breakpoints and the points where debugger caught the breakpoint.

Comment: In your `WindbnbListing` make all properties optional. That is,
 add `?` to host_name, host_since, host_thumbnail_url and host_picture_url.
 With that, your code works well for me. To further debug your code, add `print("---> error: \(error)")` to your `catch`.

Comment: Oh wow, ok! That worked @workingdogsupportUkraine! Do you have an explanation as to why?

Comment: This actually works for me without making any changes. The above suggestion would work if you are expecting nil values to be returned for some properties. I second adding `print("---> error: \(error)")` to your catc to see what the error could be.

Comment: The reason is simple, sometimes one or more of those properties are in the data and sometimes there are not. There are optional. The API docs should mention which are optionals.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @workingdogsupportUkraine !

> In your WindbnbListing make all properties optional. That is, add ? to host_name, host_since, host_thumbnail_url and host_picture_url. With that, your code works well for me. To further debug your code, add print("---> error: (error)") to your catch. –
> workingdog support Ukraine

Comment: Instead of blindly making every property optional, why not look at the decoding error and see why your JSON parsing is failing? Then you can properly fix your data model struct.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, and the errors showed that these shoud be optionals, because occasionally these properties are missing.

Comment: Gotcha, for some reason my errors would appear nil.